# How to detach and append to relevant div only jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to detach the div from the relevant parent and then append to the same parent div.

```
//Jquery Code
jQuery(function(){
    moveColorDots();

});
function moveColorDots(){
    var copyDivData = jQuery('.variations_form.wvs-archive-variation-wrapper').detach();
    copyDivData.appendTo('.product-variations');
}
```

```
<div class="pp-content-post">
    <div class="variations_form wvs-archive-variation-wrapper">
      some data here
    </div>
    <div class="product-box">
        <div class="glasses-sec">
            <h3>title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="product-variations"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Expected result.
[image]

But after running the above code I am getting the following result.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [.detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) Description: Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

That means you append all the detached elements to every `product-variations` element ..So

- You need to loop through the `variations_form.wvs-archive-variation-wrapper` elements by using `.each()`
- Also you can use `.appendTo()` directly

```js
//Jquery Code
jQuery(function(){
    moveColorDots();

});
function moveColorDots(){
    jQuery('.variations_form.wvs-archive-variation-wrapper').each(function(){
     var product_variations = jQuery(this).next('div').find('.product-variations');
     jQuery(this).appendTo(product_variations);
    });
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pp-content-post">
    <div class="variations_form wvs-archive-variation-wrapper">
      some data here 1
    </div>
    <div class="product-box">
        <div class="glasses-sec">
            <h3>title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="product-variations"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pp-content-post">
    <div class="variations_form wvs-archive-variation-wrapper">
      some data here 2
    </div>
    <div class="product-box">
        <div class="glasses-sec">
            <h3>title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="product-variations"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** This line of code `var product_variations = jQuery(this).next('div').find('.product-variations');` is depending on your html structure it works for the posted html here .. But if you've another html structure you need to modify it to catch the desired element